# Excel VBA - Copy entire columns from closed Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I've got an Excel workbook with a lot of information that I want to pull out and insert into a this new workbook where this macro is contained.

What I'm really after is a general function that takes a couple of arguments like sourcefile and column. I only need columns, but the entire column from the source file.

This is how I'm picturing the function to look like (pseudo code)

```
Public Function getColumnFromWorkbook(ByVal strSourceFile, ByVal sourceWorksheet)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strSourceFile, True, True)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(destSheet)
        .column(1) = wb.Worksheets(sourceWorksheet).Columns(sourceColumn)
    End With        
End Function
```

The function above probably don't work. But it might show what I'm essentially after :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work for me - note I have extended the parameter list. No error checking.

```
Public Function getColumnFromWorkbook(ByVal strSourceFile As String, ByVal sourceWorksheetName As String, ByVal sourceColumn As Long, ByVal destSheet As Worksheet)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strSourceFile, True, True)
    wb.Worksheets(sourceWorksheetName).Columns(sourceColumn).Copy (destSheet.Columns(1))
    wb.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Comment: Hmm, how do I call this function from a sub? I'm thinking mainly of the arguments really, especially the last one 'destSheet As Worksheet'

Comment: I tested with this --- getColumnFromWorkbook "TEST book.xlsx", "xyz", 3, ActiveSheet --- but you can put in any sheet in the final parameter e.g. ThisWorkbook.Sheets("hunting_dog_taxonomy")